# How to merge two time series of different lengths, replace by zeros empty dates using Octave

Tags: plot, merge, time-series, octave

I am using Octave, and I have two time series [n,2] and [m,2], n and m are dates. but the lengths don't match, I want to merge these two time series by date, and where there is only one value I want it to be a zero:

First set:

```
DATE Diference  
     2020-10-26 00:07:20              -1.1050
     2020-10-26 00:12:20                  -1.0463
     2020-10-26 00:17:20    -1.1800
     2020-10-26 00:22:20    -1.2138  
     2020-10-26 00:27:20    -1.2613  
     2020-10-26 00:32:20    -1.3488  
     2020-10-26 00:37:20    -1.2937  
     2020-10-26 00:42:20    -1.3275  
     2020-10-26 00:47:20    -1.3062  
     2020-10-26 00:52:20    -1.3250  
     2020-10-26 00:57:20    -1.2675
```

Second Set:

```
DATE:                   Temperature  
    2020-10-18 00:00:38 0.6800  
    2020-10-18 00:01:31 0.7700  
    2020-10-18 00:02:24 0.8400  
    2020-10-18 00:03:32 0.9200  
    2020-10-18 00:09:23 0.7800  
    2020-10-18 00:10:16 0.7800
```

Result:

```
    DATE:               Temperature   Diference  
     2020-10-18 00:00:38    0.6800          0  
     2020-10-18 00:01:31    0.7700          0  
     2020-10-18 00:02:24    0.8400          0  
     2020-10-18 00:03:32    0.9200          0
     2020-10-18 00:17:20    0.0           -1.10508
     2020-10-18 00:09:23    0.7800          0  
     2020-10-18 00:10:16    0.7800          0
     2020-10-26 00:12:20    0.0           -1.0463
     2020-10-26 00:17:20    0.0           -1.1800
```

All this because I want to plot Temperature v/s Difference in a scatter plot.

I have tried merging with intersect, but this matches only the dates that are common.

Comment: Please format your data series in colums, using the triple backticks if needed. As it is, your data are difficult to read.

Comment: This is much clearer. But your two series do not have any date in common?

Comment: I put in a small selection, I have data for the whole month, where some dates match and some don't.

Comment: Would you mind giving some feedback on the answer below?

Comment: Hi, yes i tried your suggestion, I first converted the serial date strings into serial darte numbers (datenum),

Comment: And since I already have the data from another project I loaded it and tried to use the script below. It gives me errors of the type: error: serie1(_,1616): out of bound 2 (dimensions are 1616x2), in the first "if" cycle: if i1 > n || serie2(i2,1) < serie1(i1,n)

Comment: it's just typos, in the comparisons one should read `serie1(i1,1)` instead of `serie1(i1,n)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your data in two arrays `serie1` and `serie2` of size `[n 2]` and `[m 2]`, both sorted by date:

```
serie = zeros(n+m,3);   % maximum possible size

i1 = 1; i2 = 1; ii = 0;
while (i1 <= n || i2 <= m)
    ii++; 
    if i1 > n || serie2(i2,1) < serie1(i1,1)
        serie(ii,1) = serie2(i2,1);
        serie(ii,2) = serie2(i2,2);
        i2++;
    elseif i2 > m || serie2(i2,1) > serie1(i1,1)
        serie(ii,1) = serie1(i1,1);
        serie(ii,3) = serie1(i1,2);
        i1++;
    else
        serie(ii,1) = serie1(i1,1);
        serie(ii,2) = serie2(i2,2);
        serie(ii,3) = serie1(i1,2);   
        i1++; i2++;
    endif   
endwhile

serie = serie(1:ii,:);
```